# create a generator that substitutes a pattern in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please consider the following list:

```
l = ['pfg022G', 'pfg022T', 'pfg068T', 'pfg130T', 'pfg181G', 'pfg181T', 'pfg424G', 'pfg424T']
```

and the file:

`example.conf`

```
"flowcell_unmapped_bams": ["/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ubam/pfg022G.unmapped.bam"],
"unmapped_bam_suffix": ".unmapped.bam",
"sample_name": "pfg022G",
"base_file_name": "pfg022G.GRCh38DH.target"
```

I would like to create a function that reads through every element of the list and looks into the file for that pattern and substitutes the pattern with the subsequent element of that list. For example the first element of the list is `pfg022G`, read through the file `example.conf` and search for `pfg022G` , once found replace to `pdf022T`.

Comment: A generator should not have side effect (change the file content? I don't understand that) -- clarify what are you asking for. Also why can't you just generate a list and create a generator out of that?

Comment: ok let's forget about generators. I just want to replace the pattern in the file with the subsequent string in. the list that matches the pattern in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two functions, for readability. You can surely combine them into one single one.

```
def replace_words(words, content):
    """List of words is supposed to have even items
    Items are extracted in pairs: Find the first word
    in content and replace with next word
    """
    _iterator = iter(words)
    for _find in _iterator:
        _replace = next(_iterator)
        content = content.replace(_find, _replace)
    return content


def rewrite_file(file, words):
    """ Open the file to modify, read its content
    then apply the replace_words() function. Once
    done, write the replaced content back to the
    file. You could compact them into one single 
    function.
    """
    content = open(file, 'r').read()
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(replace_words(words, content))



FILENAME = 'example.conf'
l = ['pfg022G', 'pfg022T', 'pfg068T', 'pfg130T', 'pfg181G', 'pfg181T', 'pfg424G', 'pfg424T']
rewrite_file(FILENAME, l)
```

Comment: this works only for the first run. after that it does not work anymore

Comment: Please explain: your sample file only contains the first word in the wordlist. Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: yes it contain only the first word but once replaced it will contain the second word in the wordlist, and once replaced again which is not the case it will contain the third word in the wordlist. This should happen until the list is exhausted

Comment: Please provide the output of what you would like `example.conf` to look like after it goes through the function.